# In Android Studio How to make Validation for imageview?

Tags: java, android, validation, imageview

**How to make validation in android studio for image view.
E.g. I have button when i click on button it open a gallery and i select image it comes in image view but how to set that if someone not upload image it will show message till not upload image in image view
Thanks.**

Answer (score 0):

The uri or bitmap that you use to save the image, use it in sharedPreferences. So that when the default value is null user will get the message but when you add a new image it will overwrite the default value of sharedPreferences and hide the messgae.